# How to remove "border-radius" from default UITextField?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitextfield

My question is, how do I remove the "`border-radius`" of the `textfield` in Swift? Is it achievable in xCode or do you need to do a customized `textfield`? If so, how do I do that? I want the default `textfield` but without it's "`border-radius`" if you know what I mean.

Help, please!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UITextField` has an attribute `borderStyle`, which can be changed either in interface builder:

[image: UITextField has an attribute borderStyle, which can be changed.]

...or in code:

```
public var borderStyle: UITextBorderStyle // default is UITextBorderStyleNone. If set to UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect, custom background images are ignored.
```

Answer (score 5):

You can set the border style using Storyboards.

[image]

And also you can set border style programitically

```
[txtUserName setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
```

Answer (score 4):

What do you exactly mean with border-radius? the border around it?
You can turn that off by clicking the button in xcode:

[image]

Or if you want to do it programmatically do:

```
myButton.bordered = false
```

Comment: What I mean by  "border-radius" is that the default text-field is rounded by the corners, how can I reverse that?

Comment: by selecting the square border in "border style"

Comment: OP's question it is about a text field not a button